# Filter matching and non-matching elements into different halves of a tuple

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there a simple and efficient way to perform the following in Scala?

```
val elements = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val (odd, even) = elements.filter(_ % 2 == 0)
```

I am aware of `groupBy`, but I would like something that works with a constant number of groups that can be extracted into separate values.

Comment: I don't think there's any particular advantage to a Tuple-based solution when the number of "groups" is greater than 2 (when there are two, `partition`, as gzm0 points out, is the best solution). Keep in mind that `TupleNN`'s `NN` is limited to 22 (to date). If you have more than that many groups, you have not choice but to use `groupBy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List.partition` does what you want:

```
val (even, odd) = elements.partition(_ % 2 == 0)
```

Note that it works only with two final groups.

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield Partition was Odersky's basic why is Scala great example, see http://www.slideshare.net/marakana/martin-odersky-whats-next-for-scala slide #9, e.g.  See also recent ML discussion of slightly different use case https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/cHwgchiSdP0